# Why will my project run on my phone but not my AVD?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created a project and it functions properly and the way I need it to. The problem is, I need it to run on my phone as well as my AVD. When I open my AVD, which is the `Nexus 5X API 28`, the AVD will open no problem but the project will not run. Here is what is presented in my `event log`. I am unable to work out what it means as I am new the android creation, but it would help if someone could tell me what it means? Thanks.

```
14:59   Project setup started
14:59   Gradle sync finished in 6 s 791 ms (from cached state)
14:59   * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
14:59   * daemon started successfully
15:00   Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.
15:00   Emulator: dsound: Could not initialize DirectSoundCapture
15:00   Emulator: dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
15:00   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
15:00   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
15:00   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
15:00   Emulator: C:\Users\PC_User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
15:00   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
15:00   Emulator: dsound: Attempt to initialize voice without DirectSoundCapture object
15:00   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
15:02   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
15:03   Gradle build finished in 1 m 35 s 896 ms
```

Comment: The logcat might have some clues...

Comment: Just so you know that log is not showing any breaking errors the only thing it's complaining about is that it can find an audio capture device to bind to the emulator I.E there is no microphone allowed to be used by the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tips that can may help you:

- Cold boot the emulator and reinstall apk.
  AVD Manager -> Actions -> Arrow Down: Cold Boot Now -> remove the app -> try to install and run it again (take a look at Logcat)

  - clean and rebuild your project: Build -> Clean Project -> Build -> Rebuild Project
  - invalidate caches and restart IDE: File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Comment: This worked and allowed the app to open, although the app is now crashing in the emulator and not on my phone so I'm not totally sure as to why. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For analysing the crash you can use the error filter in Logcat where you can see exception reporting. Take a look at the official android developers site: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat